# What is the difference between Enable a job and Start a job in Sql Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job

Well, I'm new to this...
I trying to understand the difference between Enabling a Sql Job and Starting a Job at a step?
The both seem to work in the same manner... or is there a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Enabling a Sql Agent Job** - means Job is active on server and will be executed on scheduled time
**Starting a Job step** - means either server has started a job step on scheduled time or you have started it forcefully,
Lets say a job has 5 steps and you don't want to execute first 3, here SQL Server Agent provide you facility that you can start a job execution from step 4.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189817.aspx

```
SELECT  [enabled] --enabled Indicates whether the job is enabled to be executed.
        ,name
FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobs
WHERE   name = 'Your Job Name'
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187387.aspx

```
SELECT  step_id,
        step_name -- Name of the job step
FROM    msdb.dbo.SysJobSteps
WHERE   job_id = ( SELECT   job_id
                   FROM      msdb.dbo.sysjobs
                   WHERE    name =  'Your Job Name'
                 )
```

Comment: so if I disable a job and then enable it.. will it start at the step where it stopped previously?

Comment: @@Tejal Job enabling\ disabling is only linked with its automated job schedules, it has no link with step sequences

Comment: ok.. thank you.. so inshort.. will have to be careful when to stop a job... hmm.. thanks :)

Comment: @@Tejal But yes on each step, next action to be performed could be settled.  Sql server Agent – >Job -> Job Properties -> Steps-> there you have two advance options “On Failure” and “On Success